# You don't have permission to access /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html on this server

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.2, magento-2.0.4

After upgrade from Magento 2.0.2 to 2.0.4 I am getting follwoing error message

- On Mini Cart

  > You don't have permission to access /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html on this server.
- On Products Page

  > Forbidden
  >   You don't have permission to access /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/gallery/gallery.html on this server.

I have upgraded system using **Web Setup Wizard**. I have taken following steps after upgrade

Index are regenerated,
Permission are applied again,
Flushed Magento Cache

Answer (score 4):

To resolve your issue with permission permanently, you need to set your primary user group in Linux to be "www-data" most of the time but you need to check your which apache belongs to.

To check which groups you belong to, type:

```
id
```

in the command line.

To change primary user group type in:

```
usermod -G oldusergroup newprimaryusergroup
```

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue but fix it using folowing step :

1. Run following command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
2. Run  `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. Run  `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
4. Run  `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Clear browser cache, you are done.

Answer (score 1):

reset the permissions like here

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

and redeploy the static content with `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

Make sure that you are assigning the right user to your files.

Other than that you can delete the whole pub/static folder except the .htaccess file and redeploy it with the command above.

Comment: I deleted the folder pub/static and executed `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` but now everything is broken even after clearing magento cache.